# What url should I provide to Matomo for an app?

Tags: typescript, react-native, matomo

So I am trying to implement Matomo tracker on my react native app. I should open an Matomo account before, but it requires an website url. What url should I provide since I want to implement it on an app and not on an website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. It asks for a url just to append it to paths and what not. It seems to be following Google's bad practice. The url there has a token value. Just to display something. No real analytics value.